# Can I export mysql databases via phpmyadmin while data still inserted into the exported databases?

Tags: mysql

Because stopping and restarting updating databases will cause lots of labor and time. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can, without checking for transactions and you need to block it anyway, your database might be or become in the middle of a write-operation, and be in a inconsistent state.

Comment: you could try as long as your export doesn't cause any locks (which could prevent inserts or updates from taking place). But you can't guarantee that the export will contain all the data that was inserted simultaneously, in fact it probably won't. So it depends what you actually need from the output. Might be quicker to do it from the command line as well if you can, rather than rely on a web GUI.

Comment: If I export databases while data still inserted via command line instead of phpmyadmin, is there any problem? Thanks.